# Adding image to word document

Tags: office-js

I have written a below simple word addin to insert an image into word document, 
but when I execute this code , image does not get added to document.

```
var img = "data:image/png;base64,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"; // assumes gets a docx file as base64

// Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
Word.run(function (context) {

    // Create a proxy object for the document body.
    var body = context.document.body;

    // Queue a command to insert the image.
    body.insertInlinePictureFromBase64(img, 'End');

    // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
    // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
    return context.sync().then(function () {
        // app.showNotification('Image inserted successfully.');
        console.log('doneeeee');
    });
})
.catch(function (error) {

});
```

Any idea what could be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove "data:image/png;base64," from the image src.